# sqlite - get a single column value - not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using c# and I cannot get any vaue. The data returns null. This is my code.

```
SQLiteConnection DBConnection;
DBConnection = GetMyconnection();
DBConnection.Open();
string DBCommand = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE setting_key = '" + setting_key + "' LIMIT 1";
using (SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(DBCommand, DBConnection))
{
    using (SQLiteDataReader DBDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (DBDataReader.Read())
        {
            object data = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            return DBDataReader.GetString(DBDataReader.GetOrdinal("setting_value"));
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}
DBConnection.Close();
```

This code is placed in a global helper function which I call from a form.

Kindly help.

Comment: side note : your code probably suffer from SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: I know that. Please let me know the error for question asked.

Answer (score 1):

The main item is saw was that you were running an ExecuteScalar on the same command as the ExecuteReader and I could see no reason why. Other things I noted was that you were concatenating the statement instead of using parameters, you only needed one value but were using `SELECT *`, and there was no exception handling. I would have a *Unique Index* on the `settingkey` column to speed up the query and prevent duplicates, so you don't need to have the `LIMIT 1` on the command

I rolled this up trying to use as much of your code as possible. I altered the SQL command to get the one value that you wanted, only using the ExecuteScalar method, and using the conditional operator instead of the `if...then` block. The actual command has been wrapped in a `try...catch` for exception handling and will provide error feedback

```
string ReturnValue;

SQLiteConnection DBConnection;
DBConnection = GetMyconnection();
DBConnection.Open();
string DBCommand = "SELECT setting_value FROM settings WHERE setting_key = @settingkey LIMIT 1";

using (SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(DBCommand, DBConnection)) {
    sqlCommand.parameters.AddWithValue("@settingkey", setting_key);

    try {
        object data = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        ReturnValue = (data != null) ? data.ToString() : "Error";
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ReturnValue = "Exception: " + ex.Message; }

}
DBConnection.Close();

return ReturnValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code read a list of row but if your query is ok work.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE setting_key = '" + setting_key + "' LIMIT 1";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
       Console.WriteLine("Name: " + reader["setting_value"] + "\tScore: " + reader["score"]);
```